# Finding sum of max and min elements of list Swi-prolog

Tags: prolog

Please help, i new in Prolog trying to find  sum of max and min elements of  list , but this  code not works.

```
max([H|[]], Max) :- Max is H,!.
max([H|T], Max) :-
    max(T, Max1),
    Max1 > H,
    Max is Max1, !.
max([H|T], Max) :-
    max(T, Max1),
    Max1 < Head,
    Max is Head, !.

minlist([Head|[]], Min) :-
    Min is Head, !.
minlist([Head|List], Min) :-
    minlist(List, Min1),
    Min1 < Head,
    Min is Min1, !.
minlist([Head|List], Min) :-
    max(List, Min1),
    Min1 > Head,
    Min is Head, !.

sum([H|T],S) :-
    S is minlist([H|T],Min) + max([H|T],Max),
    !.
```

Comment: @vanilla: That's not a duplicate!

Comment: *This code not works*. Did you write that code? What have you done to narrow down the problem? In what way does it not work? What is your specific question?

Comment: @lurker I wrote that code, min and max predicates does not calld from sum.I dont know how it works

Comment: In Prolog there's a difference between a predicate and an arithmetic function. You can define a predicate nit SWI Prolog does not let you define your own arithmetic function. You'll need to call it separately. `minlist([H|T],Min), max([H|T],Max), S is Min + Max.`

Comment: The presence of so many cuts is also an alarm bell to me. `[Head|[]]` would be more clearly rendered `[Head]`. I think there is a general confusion here about how to approach this problem and I would strongly recommend returning to the books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cut at the end of each predicate clause definition is unnecessary. The purpose of the cut is to intentionally prune unwanted but otherwise valid solutions to a solution search.

In Prolog, there's a difference between an *arithmetic function* and a *predicate*. An *arithmetic function* returns a value (as do functions in other languages) and are only used with operators that evaluate arithmetic expressions (such as `is/2`, `>/2`, `=:=/2`, etc). SWI Prolog does not allow you to define your own arithmetic functions.

A predicate is a term that you query. They do not return a value as a function does. They merely succeed or fail and will instantiate variables in the arguments as needed to establish success. Further, on a query, Prolog will find as many different instantiations of variables as it can to succeed, thus possibly yielding multiple solutions. The the cut is intended to prune that process when desired. In Prolog, you can define your own predicates.

A simple example of the difference would be a predicate for minimum of two values:

```
min(A, B, A) :- A < B.
min(A, B, B) :- A >= B.
```

You would query this to get a result:

```
?- min(4, 2, M).
M = 2.
```

Prolog has a `min/2` arithmetic function would would be used as follows:

```
?- M is min(4, 2).
M = 2.
```

In the case of your code, you have defined a *predicate* for the maximum value off a list. Here is your predicate, but rewritten to deal with the following issues:

- You're using `is/2` as an assignment operator, which it isn't intended for. You want *unification* which can be done directly with the arguments (as shown below) or using `=/2`.
- You have a typo: using `Head` when you meant `H`.
- Rename to `max_list` to indicate it works with lists

Rewritten to avoid the cuts and the unnecessary use of `is/2` to do "assignment":

```
max([H], H).               % The max of list [H] is H
max([H|T], Max) :-
    max(T, Max),
    Max > H.
max([H|T], H) :-
    max(T, Max1),
    Max1 < H.
```

We can actually do a little better than this because your second and third clauses `min([H|T], ...)` which match the query `min([H], ...)` as does the first clause. That will result in unnecessary matching that can be avoided. You can handle this by ensuring lists in 2nd and 3rd clauses are at least two elements:

```
max_list([H], H).               % The max of list [H] is H
max_list([X,Y|T], Max) :-
    max([Y|T], Max),
    Max > X.
max_list([X,Y|T], H) :-
    max([Y|T], Max1),
    Max1 < X.
```

One further issue with this implementation is you will redundantly call `max/2` depending upon whether `Max > X` succeeds or fails. The more "textbook" implementation for `max_list`, which avoids this issue and is tail recursive, would be:

```
max_list([X|Xs], M) :-
    max_list(Xs, X, M).

max_list([], M, M).
max_list([X|Xs], Xm, M) :-
    X > Xm,
    max_list(Xs, X, M).
max_list([X|Xs], Xm, M) :-
    X =< Xm,
    max_list(Xs, Xm, M).
```

You can define `min_list/2` similarly.

Then `sum/2` would be written as:

```
sum(L, S) :-
    min_list(L, Lmin),
    max_list(L, Lmax),
    S is Lmin + Lmax.
```